# Does this usage of "so too (without comma in-between)" sound natural?

Tags: grammar

I am reading a book about longevity and have run into a sentence using "so too (without comma in-between)" which makes me curious whether it sounds natural to native speakers.

It goes,

**Just as individually we need to restructure our life course, *so too* our institutions and policies that provide social insurance and support to those with few resources or who experience economic misfortune need to change.**

My question is, if *so too* is already used, wouldn't *need to change* at the end of the sentence sound unnatural?

I think it would've sound more natural to me if "so too" had been "so do" and there hadn't been *need to change* at the end.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Structure: so too **do** [our etc] **need** to change. He needs to clean up his room, so too **does** his little sister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was “so do” without “need to change” on the end than that would change the meaning, because it would be saying that institutions and policies need to restructure their life courses (which doesn’t really make sense, especially for policies), and not that they need to change. “So too” is correct for introducing a second concept that’s analogous to the first in some way but not exactly the same. The whole sentence is a little stilted, but perfectly grammatical.